# Why can't I reference my nested class in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a nested class structure with multiple levels like this:

```
public class L1 {
  public static class L2 {
    public static class L3 {
      public enum MyEnum {
        E1,
        E2,
        E3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to reference `MyEnum` in my Thymeleaf template. What I expect from the usual syntax is that this should work:

```
${T(com.my.packages.L1.L2.L3.MyEnum).E1}
```

However, this does not work and gives me the following error:

> EL1005E: Type cannot be found (com.my.packages.L1.L2.L3.MyEnum)

To investigate I went step by step, checking whether I could reference *any* type like that at all. So, I simply tried to reference `L1` first.

```
${T(com.my.packages.L1).E1}
```

This time I got an error telling me that `L1` does not have a field `E1`. So the conclusion here is that Thymeleaf successfully referenced `L2`.

I tried the same thing with `L2` and that "worked" as well. Same as with `L1`.

Then I tried `L3` and Thymeleaf again failed to reference that type.

Does Thymeleaf have some sort of "maximum depth" when it comes to nested classes? Or do I need some alternative syntax in that case? Looking for this problem online is very difficult because every article I find simply shows me the above syntax, which works in principle, and doesn't consider nested classes.

I know I could probably just un-nest the classes and be done with it, but I'm not supposed to change the structure for other reasons, so that's a sub-optimal option.

Comment: After `L1` replace the `.` with an `$` this indicates a nested class else it is interpreted as the next level in a package. Something like `${T(com.my.packages.L1$L2$L3$MyEnum).E1}`, I'm not entirely sure if you need the last `$` or if that can be a `.`. You should see the same if you do a `System.out.println(MyEnum.class.getName())` which should print something similar.

Comment: @M.Deinum Used L1$L2$L3.MyEnum and it worked like a charm. Please post this as an answer that I can accept so that others quickly see the correct solution.

Comment: Note that this isn't specific to Thymeleaf, but is an artifact of how Java classes are actually named during compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using nested classes you need to use `$` as the separator and not the `.` notation. The `.` is for package while the `$` is used for nested classes.

If you would do a `System.out.println(L1.L2.L3.MyEnum.class.getName());` The output would be something like the following

```
your.package.L1$L2$L3$MyEnum
```

To use the enum in an expression you have to follow the same naming pattern.

`${T(com.my.packages.L1$L2$L3$MyEnum).E1}` or `${T(com.my.packages.L1$L2$L3.MyEnum).E1}` should do the trick.